# Function returing null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the value from an number input type but when i try to show the value it returns a null (ps: sorry I'm still a highschool student)
HTML:

```
  <label for="nummatch"><h2>Number of Match/es:</h2></label>
        <input type="number" onkeyup="stop(this)" id="nummatch" name="number of matches" value="1" min="1" max="5">
        <br>
        <a  href="../html/Game Page.html#vsComputer"><button onclick="number()"><h1>VS Computer</h1></button></a>
```

JavaScript

```
   function number(){
       var times = document.getElementById("nummatch").value;
       return timesNum;
    }
       var time = number();
       console.log(time)
```

the console.log returns a error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')"

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you're returning a different variable name inside the 'number' function.

Here is a correct JavaScript code with full HTML Code:

Finally, I hope that's clear and helpful, Thanks!.

```html
<label for="nummatch"><h2>Number of Match/es:</h2></label>
<input type="number" onkeyup="stop(this)" id="nummatch" name="number of matches" value="1" min="1" max="5">
<br>
<a href="../html/Game Page.html#vsComputer"><button onclick="number()"><h1>VS Computer</h1></button></a>


<script>
    function number() {
        var times = document.getElementById("nummatch").value;
        return times;
    }
    var time = number();
    console.log(time)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing. You add a onkeyup event which calls the function stop(). I add this function to your code and it works well.

```js
function stop() {
  var time = number();
  console.log(time)
}

function number(){
  var times = document.getElementById("nummatch").value;
  return times;
}
```

```html
  <label for="nummatch"><h2>Number of Match/es:</h2></label>
  <input type="number" onkeyup="stop(this)" id="nummatch" name="number of matches" value="1" min="1" max="5">
  <br>
  <a  href="../html/Game Page.html#vsComputer"><button onclick="number()"><h1>VS
```